# Разница между addEventListener и onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, javascript-events

Читал https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest, раздел Отслеживание процесса загрузки. Там приведен код

```js
oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);
```

и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/%D0%A1_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C - Шаг 3 -простой пример

```js
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };
function alertContents(httpRequest) {

    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
            alert(httpRequest.responseText);
        } else {
            alert('С запросом возникла проблема.');
        }
    }

}
```

В чем разница по производимому действию между `addEventListener` и `onreadystatechange` в данном конкретном случае?

Answer (score 1):

`readystatechange` - точно такое же событие, как и `load`, `progress` и т.д.

Способов добавить обработчик событию - два

1. задать соответствующее свойство, начинающееся с `on`
2. воспользоваться функцией `.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Нет никакой разницы. `addEventListener()` позволяет повесить на событие слушателя не удаляя остальных слушателей. То есть можно повесить на одно событие два разных слушателя или два одинаковых.

Удалить слушателя можно методом `removeEventListener()`.

Подробнее тут: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Можно остановить выполнение цепочки событий методом `event.stopPropagation()`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp

Помимо этого можно отменять стандартные действия браузера по текущему событию методом `event.preventDefault()`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp